# mixture regression model with networked variables

Tags: distributions, stochastic-processes, multinomial-distribution, mixture-distribution, dirichlet-process

I am thinking about the following regression model; In my regression model, there is prior information on the regressors that they are connected like a network $T$. The purpose of my regression model is incorporating this network and clustering the variables (nodes in the network) not only based on the prior connectivity but in the regression framework and considering the outcome variable. I believe this type of model are regression mixture models. But this one has a bit tweak in incorporating the network.

In regression mixture models, $\mathbf{w}$ is not sampled from normal distribution but a mixture of distribution (in this case, normal distribution or multinomial). The number of distribution for the mixture model comes from an stochastic process that clusters the network randomly.

$\mathbf{z}$ is a binary vector in size $1 \times p$ and if $z_i = 1$ it means that neighbours of the node $i$ are in the same cluster.

The total number of clusters (sum of z) comes from a Poisson distribution.

\begin{equation}
\textrm{p}(\sum_{l} z_{l}) = \frac{\alpha^{\sum_{l} z_{l}} e^{-\alpha}}{(\sum_{l} z_{l})!}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\textrm{p}(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha^{\omega_{1} - 1} e^{-\alpha/\omega_2}}{\omega_{2}^{\omega_{1}} \Gamma(\omega_{1})}
\end{equation}

Given the value of $z$ there would be random clusters in $\mathbf{w}$. For example

```
z = [0,0,1,0,1] = , w = [2.1, 2.1, 2.1, 1.1, 1.0]
z = [0,0,1,1,0] = , w = [2.1, 1.1, 1.0, 1.1, 1.0]
z = [1,1,1,1,1] = , w = [2.1, 1.1, 0.0, 3.1, 4.0]
z = [1,0,1,0,1] = , w = [2.1, 1.1, 0.0, 0.1, 2.0]
...
```

Please don't get confused by the value of $z$ and $w$. $z$ is just an indicator which nodes are selected for the stochastic process and how nodes/variables will be clustered and which node is in which cluster.

I can imagine the $\mathbf{w}$ can be either be a categorical (multinomial) distribution (if the $w$ in the same cluster be same) or mixture of Gaussian.

Basically, I would like to derive p(D|w) in order to use this model for clustering purpose. If the question still is not clear, please let me know.

Comment: It is not clear precisely how $\mathrm w$ is related to $z$.  You also do not provide any information about how the components of the vector $z$ are distributed.  To make this into an answerable question, please edit it to clarify those points.  Consider describing your "process" more concretely, rather than in abstract mathematical terms.  (The abstract formulation leaves out information that may be useful in answering your question.)